# Setting a value to a cell in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
K = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4], "B":[5,6,7,8]})
```

Then I set the cell in the first row and first column to 11:

```
K.iloc[0]["A"] = 11
```

And when I check the dataframe again, I see that the value assignment is done and K.iloc[0]["A"] is equal to 11. However when I add a column to this data frame and do the same operation for a cell in the new column, the value assignment is not successful:

```
K["C"] = 0
K.iloc[0]["C"] = 11
```

So, when I check the dataframe again, the value of K.iloc[0]["C"] is still zero. I appreciate if somebody can tell me what is going on here and how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `K.iloc[0]["C"]`, you first take the first line, so you have a copy of a slice from your dataframe,  then you take the column C. So you change the copy from the slice, not the original dataframe.

That your first call, `K.iloc[0]["A"] = 11` worked fine was in some sens a luck.

The good habit is to use loc in "one shot", so you have access to the original value of the dataframe, not on a slice copy :

```
K.loc[0,"C"] = 11
```

Be careful that iloc and loc are different function, even if they seems quite similar here.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, I would do the operations in a different order and use `loc`:

```
K.loc[0, 'C'] = 0
K.loc[0, ['A', 'C']] = 11
```

Answer (score 2):

**If default index**, `RangeIndex` is possible use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), but it set index values by label `0` (what is same like position 0):

```
K['C'] = 0
K.loc[0, ["A", "C"]] = 11
print (K)
    A  B   C
0  11  5  11
1   2  6   0
2   3  7   0
3   4  8   0
```

Reason why your solution failed is possible find in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters):

> This can work at times, but it is not guaranteed to, and therefore should be avoided:
>
> dfc['A'][0] = 111

Solution with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is possible with get positions of columns by [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
print (K.columns.get_indexer(["A", "C"]))
[0 2]

K['C'] = 0
K.iloc[0, K.columns.get_indexer(["A", "C"])] = 11
print (K)
    A  B   C
0  11  5  11
1   2  6   0
2   3  7   0
3   4  8   0
```

Answer (score 2):

`loc` should work :

```
K.loc[0]['C'] = 11
K.loc[0, 'C'] = 11
```

Both the above versions of `loc` will be able to assign values to the dataframe `K`.